# Chef FileEdit keep creating new file

Tags: chef-infra

i have a simple insert_line_if_no_match in my recipe that seems to keep re-creating the file in each subsequent chef-client run.

after reading the rubydoc page of FileEdit, it says it will only write a new file if the file has changed but this doesn’t seem to be true.

anyone else have this problem?

ruby_block “provide_useful_default_prompt" do

```
block do
    profile = Chef::Util::FileEdit.new("/etc/profile")
    profile.insert_line_if_no_match(/PS1/, "\nPS1='[\\! (\\h):\\W] '\n")
    profile.write_file
end
```

end

more /etc/profile | grep PS1

PS1='[! (\h):\W] '
end

Comment: That regex isn't matching for some reason. Open a Ruby console and try it out

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using the `line` cookbook.  It has some LWRP's there that we use a lot.  For example:

```
replace_or_add "provide_useful_default_prompt" do
  path    "/etc/profile"
  pattern "PS1"
  line    "PS1='[\\! (\\h):\\W] '\n"
  action  :edit
end
```

Remember to include `depends 'line'` in your `metadata.rb` and `cookbook 'line'` in `Berksfile` if you use it.